# Matching incomplete string in Python dictionary

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

I'm working with a dictionary where keys are strings (often multiple words) and values are integers. Here's a simplified representation of the dictionary:

```
{
...
'X ontology entity': 0, 
'X entity': 1, 
'image quality': 10, 
'right lower kidney': 10, 
'magnetic resonance imaging': 10312, 
'MR imaging': 10312, 
 ...
}
```

**Problem Statement:**
I need to iterate over the keys in this dictionary and match them against a series of tokens extracted from a text. For example, consider the following text:

```
MR imaging shows that the patient suffers from infection in right lower kidney.
```

I split this text into tokens using whitespace. The goal is to match entire key phrases (like "MR imaging" and "right lower kidney") from the dictionary with these tokens.

**Current Approach:** So far, I've written code that can successfully identify "MR imaging" but fails to recognize "right lower kidney." Here's my current code:

```
found = []
for i, t in enumerate(tokens):
    term = [tokens[i]]
    j = deepcopy(i)
    while (' '.join(term) in self.db_terms):
        if j < len(tokens):
            j += 1
            term.append(tokens[j])
    found.append(' '.join(term[:-1]))
return set(found)
```

The issue arises because "right lower" is not a key in the dictionary, so my code misses the complete phrase "right lower kidney".

I'm looking for suggestions on how to modify my approach to capture multi-word keys like "right lower kidney". Any advice on optimizing the code to handle such cases effectively would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are dealing with Ngrams. Note, this answer assumes there are many keys in your dictionary as opposed to possible N-grams. In this case, it is more efficient to generate n-grams from the text as opposed to iterating over the dictionary keys (as is the case with the other answer).

Start with defining the `keys` dictionary.

```
keys = {
'X ontology entity': 0, 
'X entity': 1, 
'image quality': 10, 
'right lower kidney': 10, 
'magnetic resonance imaging': 10312, 
'MR imaging': 10312, 
}
```

You will need to generate all N-grams within a range (that you decide), and for each n-gram, determine whether it exists as a key in your dictionary.

```
import re

def get_ngrams(tokens, ngram_range):
    return {' '.join(tokens[i:i+r]) 
        for i in range(len(tokens)) for r in range(*ngram_range)}

ngram_range = (1, 4) # Right exclusive.
tokens = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', text).split()
found_tokens = set(filter(keys.__contains__, get_ngrams(tokens, ngram_range)))

print(found_tokens)
# {'MR imaging', 'right lower kidney'}
```

Keep in mind, for larger ranges and strings, this becomes an expensive operation.

---

You can optimise a bit by recognising that not all N-grams need to be stored in memory before filtering. We can save big time using a generator and loop:

```
def ngrams_generator(tokens, ngram_range):
    yield from (' '.join(tokens[i:i+r]) 
        for i in range(len(tokens)) for r in range(*ngram_range))

found_ngrams = set()
for ngram in ngrams_generator(tokens, ngram_range):
    if ngram in keys:
        found_ngrams.add(ngram)

print(found_ngrams)
# {'MR imaging', 'right lower kidney'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it the other way — start with keys and see if the key is in the sentence. It's certainly simpler. Whether it is efficient (or efficient enough) depends on how large your inputs are.

```
d = {
    'X ontology entity': 0, 
    'X entity': 1, 
    'image quality': 10, 
    'right lower kidney': 10, 
    'magnetic resonance imaging': 10312, 
    'MR imaging': 10312, 
}

sentence = "MR imaging shows that the patient suffers from infection in right lower kidney."

[key for key in d.keys() if key in sentence]
# ['right lower kidney', 'MR imaging']
```

Comment: Would only make sense if there were less keys than possible N-grams. Please make that _very_ clear here.

Comment: Without more info from the OP, we don't know if the relative sizes of the sentence or dictionary warrant doing anything beyond the simplest solution to both read and write.

Comment: Sure, but your answer does hinge on that assumption and I just wanted to make sure it was clear. :) I did not downvote you, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the items and build a new `dict`, this can be done using a comprehension.

```
sentence = "MR imaging shows that the patient suffers from infection in right lower kidney."
tokens = {
    ...
    'X ontology entity': 0, 
    'X entity': 1, 
    'image quality': 10, 
    'right lower kidney': 10, 
    'magnetic resonance imaging': 10312, 
    'MR imaging': 10312, 
     ...
}

#Just in case, force lowercase
sencence = sentence.lower()

filtered = {token: value for token, value in tokens.items() if token.lower() in _sentence}
print(filtered)
#{'MR imaging', 'right lower kidney'}
```

Then you can put them into the sentence like this:

```
for token, value in filtered.items():
    idx = _sentence.index(token.lower())
    sentence = "{} ({}){}".format(sentence[:idx+len(token)], value, sentence[idx+len(token):])
print(sentence)
#MR imaging (10312) shows that the patient suffers from infection in right lower kidney (10).
```